# google auth library node js: unpacking contents of token

Tags: google-auth-library-nodejs

Some google service is sending the program an Authorisation JWT token in the header of a request. Using the Google Auth Library (https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs), how can I unpack the package to retrieve a field of the token? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found making a request to: `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=` and passing the token returns the json.